# A question about Python OOP __init__ method

Tags: python, oop

I have a short question about Python OOP's `__init__` method and is here for help.

Let's say I have a module called `basic_backend.py` which has the following code:

```
items = list()


def create_items(app_items):

    global items
    items = app_items
```

Then I have another MVC module, in which I wrote:

```
import basic_backend

class ModelBasic(object):

    def __init__(self, app_items):
        self._item_type = 'product'
        self.create_items(app_items)
```

My question is, in the `__init__` method, I was able to use `self` to call the function from an imported module. Why am I able to do this please? I am not sure about the theory behind this.

Guru please help!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You *didn't* call a function from the imported module. You called a method on `ModelBasic` instances (one you didn't show us the code for). Where do you get the idea you're calling the function from `basic_backend`?

Comment: You're not using the same variables there.

Comment: That code can't work as shown, because `ModelBasic` doesn't define a `create_items()` method.

Comment: Your code as shown does nothing but create an empty list, define a function and a class. You never use the function or the class to create any objects. If you try to create a class with `ModelBasic` it will throw an `AttributeError`

Comment: Hey, guys. I have figured out the error. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the code here.

`self.create_items(app_items)` is not calling *basic_backend*’s function, it is calling a *ModelBasic* function that doesn’t exist.

`self` is a variable that is a reference to the current object

```
def __init__(self, app_items):
    self._item_type = 'product'
    self.create_items(app_items)
```

In here, you can see that the first argument is self, it could be named anything, but it’s a convention to name it self.

What pythons does when it calls this method is that it passes the current object to the first argument. `self.item_type` is saying *take this object, and define variable item_type as string 'product'*

However, `self.create_items(app_items)` will fail because your object doesn’t have a method app_items.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think that's the correct answer. I went back and check the code. It's exactly the same as you described. I really appreciate it!